# Successful compilation but blank web page

Tags: angular-material

i am new to Angular and i have encountered a blank web page and the following error despite my application compiling successfully.

ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:7:129 - error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/----------/news-app/node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts' 
is not a module.

7 import { MatButtonModule, MatCardModule, MatMenuModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule, MatSidenavModule, MatListModule } from '@angular/material';

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

In Angualar 9 material components can no longer be imported from `@angular/material`.

Use the individual secondary entry-points, such as `@angular/material/button` for `MatButtonModule`

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17503

Comment: Thank you! the application is now working, i imported each component individually.